Sequential source switching using structured streaming
I am developing an Apache Spark Structured Streaming application that needs to first process historical data stored as Avro files (these are the Kafka archive files) in HDFS and then, when completely finished, transition to processing real-time data from a Kafka topic. I'm looking for a fault-tolerant design to handle this scenario.
The first approach I have in mind is :

Reading Avro Files: I use spark.read.format("avro").load("hdfs://...") to load Avro files.
Switching to Kafka Streaming: I configure Kafka streaming with readStream.format("kafka")....

However, I am unsure how to ensure this process is fault-tolerant.
How would you proceed to do a similar task?
Context: I am trying to achieve a behavior similar to Apache Flink hybrid source using structured streaming: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/hybridsource/

Question out of idle curiosity: Since Flink already added this kind of convenience function, why are you not using Flink?
Real question: What do you mean by "fault-tolerant" here (or rather - what aspect of fault-tolerance is important to you)?

For choosing Spark over Apache Flink, it's primarily an exploratory choice. I'm interested in assessing whether similar functionality can be implemented in Spark without switching platforms. Regarding fault-tolerance, I'm focused on achieving exactly-once semantics during the transition from processing historical Avro files to real-time Kafka. This entails a system capable of rolling back to a consistent state without full reprocessing in case of failures, particularly when switching between these sources.
